# How to use a DataContract for the first element in a nested json array?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, datacontractserializer, datacontract

The objective is to instruct the serializer using DataContract to store the first element only, allowing me to eliminate the use of `IList<MyObject>`

### Sample JSON

```
{
    "registrant_contacts": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "type": 1,
            "name": "Dns Admin",
            "organization": "Google Inc.",
            "address": "Please contact contact-admin@google.com, 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
            "city": "Mountain View",
            "zip": "94043",
            "state": "CA",
            "country": null,
            "country_code": "US",
            "phone": "+1.6502530000",
            "fax": "+1.6506188571",
            "email": "dns-admin@google.com",
            "url": null,
            "created_on": null,
            "updated_on": null
        }
    ]
}
```

### Sample DataContract

```
[DataContract]
public class RegistrantContact
{

    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public object id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="type")]
    public int type { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="organization")]
    public string organization { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="address")]
    public string address { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="city")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="zip")]
    public string zip { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="state")]
    public string state { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="country")]
    public object country { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="country_code")]
    public string country_code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="phone")]
    public string phone { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="fax")]
    public string fax { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="email")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="url")]
    public object url { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="created_on")]
    public object created_on { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="updated_on")]
    public object updated_on { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Example
{

    [DataMember(Name="registrant_contacts")]
    public IList<RegistrantContact> registrant_contacts { get; set; }
}
```

### Sample Serialize Code

```
public static async Task<Example> GetExample() {
    Example record = new Example();

    using ( WebClient wc = new WebClient() ) {
        wc.Headers.Add( "Accept", "application/json" );

        try {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof( Example ) );
            using ( Stream s = await wc.OpenReadTaskAsync( "https://example.com/sample.json" ) ) {
                record = ser.ReadObject( s ) as Example;
            }
        } catch ( SerializationException se ) {
            Debug.WriteLine( se.Message );
        } catch ( WebException we ) {
            Debug.WriteLine( we.Message );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            Debug.WriteLine( e.Message );
        }
    }
    return record;
}
```

### Objective

To change

```
public IList<RegistrantContact> registrant_contacts { get; set; }
```

Into

```
public RegistrantContact registrant_contacts { get; set; }
```

By altering the `[DataMember(Name="registrant_contacts")]` line so it uses the first element from the `registrant_contacts` array as the only result during the transform.

Result, means that instead of calling `response.registrant_contacts[0]` to access the nested properties `id`, `type`, `name`, etc - I can simply call `response.registrant_contacts`

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want just *By altering the `[DataMember(Name="registrant_contacts")]` line*,  Are you open to other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in two ways - first is to temporary store the data into some list and then to say .FirstOrDefault(); or second is directly to try saying it, but I believe you will have complications. So, just create a temporary list and the extract everything what you need from it. The the data contract could be whatever you like.

Comment: To do a temporary list would require setting up two classes and then painfully copy the properties over.  I considered it, but felt that DataContracts would provide some way to return the first element of an array

Comment: Then you can use .ToArray. The arrays have methods First() and Last(). But still you need to convert, it is not possible to get it out of the box (at least I can't remember a way). If this helps, please up-vote my answer.

Comment: I will upvote for the attempt.  It does not resolve the issue.